# phpunit assertRegExp() test passes in unix, fails in windows

Tags: php, regex, windows, phpunit

I have a PHPUnit Test which validates the output of a logfile with a regexp. The logfile looks like this(First line is empty, but I don't know how to display that here):

```
<empty line>
lfworker01:
-----------------------------------------------------------
Last update:               2012-06-14 11:43:17
Last Segment Sent:         2009-12-02 23:25:00 (1259792700)
Current Segement:          2009-12-03 00:25:00 (1259796300)
Clicks processed Segment:  3
Open sessions Segment:     1
Duration Segment:          0,06 sec
Speed Segment:             47,67 clicks/sec
Uptime:                    0 days 00:00:00
Clicks processed overall:  3
Avg Speed overall:         81,70 clicks/sec
Current memory used:       16,75 MB
Max memory used:           16,75 MB
```

I am validating the content with a regex:

```php
    $strExpectedMeasurementLog = "#
lfworker01:
-----------------------------------------------------------
Last update:               \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
Last Segment Sent:         2009-12-02 23:25:00 \(1259792700\)
Current Segement:          2009-12-03 00:25:00 \(1259796300\)
Clicks processed Segment:  3
Open sessions Segment:     1
Duration Segment:          \d*,\d{2} sec
Speed Segment:             \d*,\d{2} clicks/sec
Uptime:                    0 days 00:00:00
Clicks processed overall:  3
Avg Speed overall:         \d*,\d{2} clicks/sec
Current memory used:       \d*,\d{2} MB
Max memory used:           \d*,\d{2} MB#";

$strActualMeasurementLog = file_get_contents( dirname( __FILE__)."/applogs/measurement.log");
self::assertRegExp( $strExpectedMeasurementLog, $strActualMeasurementLog);
```

The PHPUnit test was created in a unix environment. This test passes in a unix test environment, but fails in a windows test environment. I have  replaced windows line breaks with unix line breaks by appyling this function to the measurement.log file:

```
public function unixtodos( $strPathFile )
{
  $strCurrent = file_get_contents( $strPathFile );

  $strPattern = "|\r\n|";
  $strReplace = "\n";
  $strNew = preg_replace( $strPattern, $strReplace, $strCurrent );

  file_put_contents( $strPathFile, $strNew );
}
```

It still doesn't match and I am out of ideas :(

Comment: If my below answer does not work it could be a bug somewhere, so please post versions of php and phpunit that you're using on each of your unix and windows environments. Also get a text editor (e.g. scite is good for this) where you can see the LF and CR bytes, as take a look at both your reports on each machine, and your phpunit source file on each machine.

Comment: Not quite, but you pointed me in the right direction to look at the LF and CR bytes and to look at the phpunit source file. Thanks Darren!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to always check the line breaks. My logfile created on a windows machine with php has unix line breaks:

[image: Logfile created with php on windows]

The PHPUnit source file checked out of CVS in unix has unix line breaks:

[image: PHPUnit Source File in unix]

The PHPUnit source file checkout out of CVS in windows has windows line breaks:

[image: PHPUnit Source File in windows]

These line breaks broke my regex validation. So now I'm always replacing line breaks to unix line breaks.

```
// replace possible windows line breaks with unix line breaks
$strExpectedMeasurementLog = preg_replace( "|\r\n|", "\n", $strExpectedMeasurementLog);
$strActualMeasurementLog = preg_replace( "|\r\n|", "\n", $strActualMeasurementLog);
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to replace all whitespace in your regex with "\s+". I.e. say "I expect some whitespace here, but I don't care exactly what it is". I think that fits your case very nicely, as it means your test won't break when the person producing the report tweaks the layout slightly. (IMPORTANT: if the whole point of your test is to catch when someone tweaks the report layout slightly, then this is the wrong approach!)

The downside is your regex becomes a horrible blur of backslashes, rather than the nice readable template you have currently. But let's have PHP do the grunt work for us; see the below example, where the preg_replace makes the regex insensitive to whitespace differences.

```
/** */
class RegexTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

function testRegex(){
$strExpectedMeasurementLog = "#
lfworker01:
-----------------------------------------------------------
Last update:               \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
Last Segment Sent:         2009-12-02 23:25:00 \(1259792700\)
Current Segement:          2009-12-03 00:25:00 \(1259796300\)
Clicks processed Segment:  3
Open sessions Segment:     1
Duration Segment:          \d*,\d{2} sec
Speed Segment:             \d*,\d{2} clicks/sec
Uptime:                    0 days 00:00:00
Clicks processed overall:  3
Avg Speed overall:         \d*,\d{2} clicks/sec
Current memory used:       \d*,\d{2} MB
Max memory used:           \d*,\d{2} MB#";

$strExpectedMeasurementLog=preg_replace("/\s+/",'\s+',$strExpectedMeasurementLog);

$strActualMeasurementLog = file_get_contents("test.lf.txt");
self::assertRegExp( $strExpectedMeasurementLog, $strActualMeasurementLog);

$strActualMeasurementLog = file_get_contents("test.crlf.txt");
self::assertRegExp( $strExpectedMeasurementLog, $strActualMeasurementLog);
}

}
```

(test.lf.txt was copy and paste from your question; test.crlf.txt was a copy of it, with LFs changed to CRLFs in my text editor.)

**REFINEMENTS**

The above is a bit crude, as it allows a space character to be used instead of a line feed. So a horribly mangled report might still pass. Which could be bad? This next version just replaces line breaks into your templates into "accept any combination of CRs and LFs":

```
$strExpectedMeasurementLog=preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/",'[\r\n]+',$strExpectedMeasurementLog);
```

And though not part of your question, this one replaces "any sequence of spaces, but not single spaces", with "require one or more spaces":

```
$strExpectedMeasurementLog=preg_replace("/ {2,}/",' +',$strExpectedMeasurementLog);
```